# .htaccess Save not existing url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

Is there a way to save the not existing url?

Lets say i go to:

www.domain.com/channel/abcd1234/

The folder abcd1234 doesn't exitst so you will be redirected to:

www.domain.com/channel/error/

Is there a way to save the first url? and getting it on the error page in a php variable?

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain/channel/error/ [R=301,L]
</ifmodule>
```

Comment: yes you can! in the last rule you can catch request uri and attach it to parameter

Comment: @JasonOOO Can you help me? Still don't get it..

Comment: @JasonOOO Can you give a code that maybe will work? can't figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of your rewrite rule you should use:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /channel/error/
```

Original 404 URL will be available to you as `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

replace by it.i wish it help you